# Code protoype Ajax.Updater to Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have problems with prototype and jquery conflict. How would this code `Ajax.Updater` in jquery?
Thanks.

```
function startCalendar(month, year) {
    new Ajax.Updater(
        'calendarInternal',
        'cldr.php',
        {
            method: 'post',
            postBody: 'action=startCalendar&month='+month+'&year='+year+''
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry - what's the question?  Is there something wrong with that code?  If so, what do you expect, what is happening that's different, and do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I believe what is being asked is - how do you replace the Ajax.Updater (prototype-js) with jQuery. On the surface it's going to be either an interval or a timeout with a jQuery.load()

Comment: Exactly,replace this code to jquery

Comment: I try this:

$('calendarInternal').load({
    url: 'cldr.php',
    type: 'POST',
   
    data: 'action=startCalendar&month='+month+'&year='+year+''
    
 })

but not working

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but... try this:

```
function startCalendar(month, year) {
    $('#calendarInternal').load('cldr.php', {
        action : 'startCalendar',
        month : month,
        year : year
    });
}
```